# Connection refused when using FTP on windows 10 laptop to connect to Mac Book

Tags: windows-10, ftp

I do not have much experience in networks and ftp, but I wanted to try to establish an ftp connection between my pc and macbook. I first tried using ftp through command prompt, but after typing "open 192.168.x.xxx", I got an error message saying connection refused. I also installed winscp and used the ftp option and put in "192.168.x.xxx", but got a similar error. I have tried disabling my firewall, but that didn't work.

One possible conflict is that my macbook is a work device and many of its network settings are blocked. However, I was able to establish a file transfer connection from my macbook to my pc (the other way around then what I wanted) using command+k. Is it possible for me to fix this on my pc, what should I do? I'm not sure what else to try?

Is it even possible for me to connect from one computer to another? I'm pretty sure the winscp FAQ said it was not, but I might have misread/misinterpreted it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Use telnet to test the connection.  https://www.google.com/search?channel=cus2&client=firefox-b-1-d&q=telnet+test+ftp

Answer (score 0):

A Mac doesn't run a FTP server out of the box. You need to install 3rd party software to make that happen.

An easier solution (if not locked down by your administrator) is to go to the "System preferences" and then select "Sharing".
Enable "File Sharing" and then click on the "Options" button. This gives another window in which you can enable "Share using SMB". (SMB is what Windows computers use.)
Don't forget to specify which user-accounts are allowed to use the sharing feature.
The Mac is now a Windows-compatible file-server.

On the Windows computer you can than just map or browse a file-share as usual. (You need to supply the Mac's user-account (and password) when you make a connection to the shares on the Mac.)